# Optimized SQL query with multiple joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am working on creating a SQL view.

I have below:

- Table A: Customer Account information
- Table B: Account relation to a subscription
- Table C: Amount Paid by Customer for each subscription and other details
- Table D: All Subscription related information

Table A :

```
AccountNum
Customer_Name
CustomerCode
```

Table B:

```
SubscriptionId
SubscriptionName
AccountNum
```

Table C:

```
SubscriptionId
AccountNum
AmountPaid
```

Table D:

```
SubscriptionId
SubscriptionName
```

I want to give the input as AccountNum and get Subscription details for his account and amount paid for each subscription for same subscription under different account and subscription details and Account Details in One Query.

Example:

```
Table A:
AccountNum   Customer_Name   CustomerCode
1234         TestName        TestCode  
12345        Testname1       TestCode1

Table B:
SubscriptionId  SubscriptionName  AccountNum
12              Netflix           1234
12              Netflix           12345

Table C:
SubscriptionId  AccountNum   AmountPaid
12              1234         100
12              12345        100

Table D:
SubscriptionId  SubscriptionName
12              Netflix 
13              Prime
```

So in the above case Account Num 1234 and 12345 is under one customer and both accounts are tied to same subscription. So i am trying to write a query for AccountNum #1234 as input and get Subscription Id, Subscription Name,  sum of amount paid for the same subscription from different account under the same customer in one single query.

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform an aggregate function and retrieve fields which are not used in 'group by' in same query as it contradicts 
You can use below query to find total amount spent per customer

```
select 
      a.CustomerCode, 
      sum(case when c.AmountPaid is not null 
               then c.AmountPaid else 0 end) as TotalAmtPaid
   from a
      inner join b
         on a.AccountNum=b.AccountNum
      inner join c
         on a.AccountNum=c.AccountNum
    where 
      a.AccountNum = ?
    group by 
      a.CustCode;
```

if you want subscription details as well then multiple rows will need to be displayed with total amount in each row, which makes no sense